# Numerically evaluating an integral related to Cantor's staircase

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration

[Cantor's staircase](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CantorFunction.html) $F_C(x)$ is a well-known "pathological" function:

```
Plot[CantorStaircase[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: the staircase]

The MathWorld link given above claims that

$$\int_0^1 F_C(x)^{F_C(x)}\mathrm dx\approx 0.750387\dots$$

`NIntegrate[]`, however, is not sufficiently able to deal with this integral without any help.

One recourse (apparently done in the MathWorld notebook) would be to split  the unit interval into the [Cantor set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CantorSet.html), integrate over those subintervals (where the staircase ought to be constant), and add up those results. This is not very efficient, since the number of subintervals grows exponentially.

> Is there a more efficient/elegant way to numerically compute $\int_0^1 F_C(x)^{F_C(x)}\mathrm dx$ (say, to fifty digits)?

My own attempts yield a result $\approx 0.75037204$, which is a bit different from the posted result. I am not sure if this is only because I undersampled the function with the Cantor set splitting I described above.

Comment: `NIntegrate[CantorStaircase[x]^CantorStaircase[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> "DoubleExponential", MinRecursion -> 15, 
 MaxRecursion -> 50]` agrees with your solution, producing `0.750372`.

Comment: How long did that evaluation take, @shrx?

Comment: 69.8 seconds. You can drop `MinRecursion` to `10` and still get the same result (at least up to the digits displayed in the output) in 4.6 seconds.

Comment: I see; DE was one of the methods I tried apart from the default `"GlobalAdaptive"`, and although it took less time, it took its sweet time before spitting out an answer. (That my computer is quite underpowered is certainly a contributing factor.)

Comment: Here's a quick benchmark: http://i.stack.imgur.com/R6o8W.png

Comment: You're looking for `NLebesgue[ ]`.It's coming in 10.5.

Comment: @shrx On my laptop I get the same result under 1 second with `NIntegrate[CantorStaircase[x]^CantorStaircase[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None}, 
 MinRecursion -> 15, MaxRecursion -> 50]`

Answer (score 12):

I don't have 50 digits. I can get close to machine precision reasonably quickly though. More importantly, there are good error bounds associated with the procedure.

Using the fact that $F_C$ assumes the values $(2k-1)/2^n$ on the intervals of length $3^n$ removed at the $n^{\text{th}}$ stage of construction of the Cantor set, we can write the integral as a double sum:

\begin{align}
  \int_0^1 F_C(x)^{F_C(x)} dx &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n} 
    \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} \left(\frac{2k-1}{2^n}\right)^{(2k-1)/2^n} \\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n-1}}{3^n} 
    \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} \left(\frac{2k-1}{2^n}\right)^{(2k-1)/2^n} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.
\end{align}

After the little rewrite to get to the last step, the inner sum is a midpoint based Riemann sum for the integral
$$I = \int_0^1 x^x dx.$$
Thus, given an $M\in\mathbb N$ we have the estimate
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{M}\frac{1}{3^n} 
  \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} \left(\frac{2k-1}{2^n}\right)^{(2k-1)/2^n} +
\frac{I}{2} \sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n.
$$
Of course, the final geometric series can easily be evaluated in closed form.
Using this, we can generate the following table of estimates in about 5 seconds:

```
i = NIntegrate[x^x, {x, 0, 1}];
results = Table[
   N[Sum[Sum[((2 k - 1)/2^n)^((2 k - 1)/2^n), {k, 1, 2^(n - 1)}]/
       3^n, {n, 1, m}]] + (2/3)^m*i, {m, 0, 16}];
Column[FullForm /@ results]
```

[image: midpoint sum results]

To 12 digits, I guess the answer is $0.750372036605$.

Here is another way to look at the error estimate. First, the sum used to approximate the integral $I$ is a midpoint sum. Thus, associated error is of the order $4^{-m}$. Furthermore, that integral is multiplied by $(2/3)^m$ yielding a total absolute error of the order $1/6^m$. Note that $1/6^{16} \approx 3\times10^{-13}$, which makes the 12 digits of accuracy seem quite reasonable.

We should even be able to use Richardson extrapolation to squeeze a couple more digits out of the process:

```
Column[
  Drop[FullForm[(6/5) #[[2]] - (1/5) #[[1]]] & /@ 
   Partition[results, 2, 1], 12]]
```

[image: Richardson results]

I guess a similar approach should work for
$$\int_0^1 f(F_C(x)) dx,$$
whenever $f$ is a well-behaved, real function; in the case considered here, we have $f(x)=x^x$.

Finally, it might be worth considering how much improvement we get for this analysis versus, say, just truncating the sum:

$$\int_0^1 F_C(x)^{F_C(x)} dx \approx \sum_{n=1}^{M}\frac{1}{3^n} 
\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} \left(\frac{2k-1}{2^n}\right)^{(2k-1)/2^n}$$

or, in *Mathematica*, with $M=16$ as above:

```
N[
 Sum[Sum[((2 k - 1)/2^n)^((2 k - 1)/2^n), {k, 1, 2^(n - 1)}]/3^n, 
{n, 1, 16}]]
(* Out: 0.749179 *)
```

This doesn't even yield 2 correct digits; the second digit is *almost* there, since $0.783431*(2/3)^{16} \approx 0.0011927$, where
$$\int_0^1 x^x dx \approx 0.78431.$$

Comment: This looks neat! If you want to try out full Richardsonian extrapolation, here's a snippet: `pts = Transpose[{6^Range[0, 1 - n, -1], results}]; Table[InterpolatingPolynomial[Take[pts, k], 0], {k, n}]`. I get `0.7503720366052` with this.

Comment: @J.M. Glad you like it!

Comment: Nice answer, I tried "truncating the sum", it is nice to see how this can be improved.